# How to increase mariabd disk space

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am getting this error and yes i tried to edit my.ini file its empty the hosting panel is cyberpanel and I cant edit it even with "VIM" and I am facing this error

```
  (/tmp/#sql-temptable-33e-26b-19a.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space                              left on device")
Jan 12 14:14:01 hidden mariadbd[830]: 2022-01-12 14:14:01 619 [ERROR] mariadbd: Disk full                              (/tmp/#sql-temptable-33e-26b-19b.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space                              left on device")
Jan 12 14:14:01 hidden mariadbd[830]: 2022-01-12 14:14:01 619 [ERROR] mariadbd: Disk full                              (/tmp/#sql-temptable-33e-26b-19c.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space                              left on device")
Jan 12 14:14:01 hidden mariadbd[830]: 2022-01-12 14:14:01 619 [ERROR] mariadbd: Disk full                              (/tmp/#sql-temptable-33e-26b-19d.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space                              left on device")
Jan 12 14:14:01 hidden mariadbd[830]: 2022-01-12 14:14:01 619 [ERROR] mariadbd: Disk full                              (/tmp/#sql-temptable-33e-26b-19e.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space                              left on device")
Jan 12 14:14:01 hidden mariadbd[830]: 2022-01-12 14:14:01 619 [ERROR] mariadbd: Disk full                              (/tmp/#sql-temptable-33e-26b-19f.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space                              left on device")
Jan 12 14:14:01 hidden mariadbd[830]: 2022-01-12 14:14:01 619 [ERROR] mariadbd: Disk full                              (/tmp/#sql-temptable-33e-26b-1a0.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space                              left on device")
Jan 12 14:14:01 hidden mariadbd[830]: 2022-01-12 14:14:01 623 [ERROR] mariadbd: Disk full                              (/tmp/#sql-temptable-33e-26f-13f.MAI); waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space
```

Comment: If the disk is full all you can do is add more disk to the file system or delete some files to make space or possibly you have exceeded your quota

Comment: You can also set [tmpdir](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#tmpdir) to a different location and/or look at the [slow query log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain-in-the-slow-query-log/) for temporary tables created on disk and look to index the tables to make those queries better.

Answer (score 0):

The disk is full.
You need to free up some space on the disk - by deleting files - or extend the disk volumes involved.

Given that a *temporary* table is involved, this could be caused by an errant query creating a very large, in-memory, resultset that it wants to join to something else.
If your database is still running and you can connect to it, see if you can locate this query.  If you can then two actions are required:

- Kill the query, which may get your system stable again, then
- Tune the query to reduce its [temporary] space requirements.

If you can't get into your database at all, then restarting the database process and/or its hosting server will kill this (and every other!) query and *should* release the temporary disk space back to the operating system.

If the problem recurs, you may need to extend the temporary (/tmp) file system further but I'd suggest keeping this in hand as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

As Phill points out, first kill the process, then figure out which query caused the disk space problem.  (The problem is on disk, not in RAM.)

Possible causes:

- A `JOIN` without an `ON` clause -- This turns it into a "Cross join"; two million row tables could generate a *trillion* row temp table.  Check the JOINs.
- Allocating a small `/tmp` on disk, then defaulting to it for temp storage.  Changing the MySQL setting for `tmpdir` may help, or it may simply delay the problem; find and fix the query first.
- Suitable `INDEXes`, especially composite indexes may help.